# google sheets timestamp script not updating when deleting or updating a range of cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, timestamp

This is my first time posting so I hope I've done everything right :)

I've implemented a script in a google sheets that creates a timestamp in column B, when a cell is edited on that row.

It works perfectly, except:

1. when I select a range of cells and press "delete", only one of the timestamps updates (the timestamp of the active cell), even though I've modified multiple cells
2. If I drag downwards to auto-fill values from one cell down into multiple cells (e.g., if I drag from A1 down to A5, to fill A2-A5 with the value that was in A1), then only the first timestamp (e.g., A2) updates, and the rest stay as they were.

Any ideas how to fix these issues?

Here's my code

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "MySheet") { //checks the column & checks the sheet is the correct one
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+10:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

And here's an example spreadsheet that has the code:

https://docs.google.com/a/eventsafetyservices.com.au/spreadsheets/d/1hFtS-diq_8QsWwqFTIlHg8zHxpvVUsDZex0nSuvXizg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally good practice to use the event object for everything related to that action.

Handling multiple rows can be handled by using the range of the event a bit further to get the extent of it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;

  if(r.getColumn() !== 2 && r.getSheet().getName() === "MySheet") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var lastRow = r.getLastRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+10:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    r.getSheet().getRange(row, 2, lastRow - row + 1, 1).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

Comment: thanks so much for that! That solves it.
I'm pretty new to javascript, and especially new to javascript within google sheets. Do you mind explaining a bit more about what e.range is and why it solved it, so I can understand?

Comment: The `e` parameter in onEdit is an event object. Event objects carry properties like the new value, the old value and the range edited. You could have solved it with `getActiveRange` but that can change between `onEdit` being called and the `getActiveRange` function being called if you work quickly. You can read more about event objects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :)